# getConstructor().getInstance(parameter) : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, class, constructor

I can' add parameter with my constructor

my code :

```
import inteToM.CreateFileAction;   // said not use import
import dto.m.CreateFile;
//...
// code
Class<?> dtoClass = Class.forName("dto.mToInte.CreateFile");
DtoM dto = (DtoM) JAXB.unmarshal(sr, dtoClass );
Class<?> actionClass = Class.forName("inteToM.CreateFileAction");

Constructor<?> actionConstruct = actionClass.getConstructor(); //dto.getClass()

ActionM aAction = (ActionIM) actionConstruct.newInstance(dto); // not working
ActionM bAction = (ActionIM) actionConstruct.newInstance();  // work
```

my class :

```
public class CreateFileAction {

import dto.mToInte.CreateFile;
public CreateFileAction () {
        System.out.println(" constructor null");
    }

    public CreateFileAction (CreateFile file) {
        System.out.println(" constructor not null");
        this.file_c= file;
    }
}
```

My error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
So I don't understand why I can't add parameter with my constructor.

edit : 
If i make this :

```
Constructor<?> actionConstruct = actionClass.getConstructor(CreateFileAction.class);
```

I have this error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: inteToM.CreateFileAction.<init>(inteToM.CreateFileAction)
```

If I make this :

```
Constructor<?> actionConstruct = actionClass.getConstructor(CreateFile.class);
```

I have this :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: inteToM.CreateFileAction.<init>(dto.m.CreateFile)
```

I Modify the dtoClass but I have the same prob.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of dto ?

Comment: I'm updating the post

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for the constructor with no arguments, then trying to call it with an argument.  You need to ask for the constructor that has an argument.

```
Constructor<?> theOtherConstructor = actionClass.getConstructor(CreateFile.class);
CreateFileAction created = theOtherConstructor.newInstance(dto);
```

**Edit**

When I first posted this, it looked like `dto` was a `CreateFile`.  Now you've changed the question.  So whatever class `dto` is, is what you need to pass in when you get the constructor, and it needs to match the type of the constructor argument.

**Another edit**

Following the discussion below, it has become clear that you have two different classes called `CreateFile`.

- The constructor is expecting `dto.mToInte.CreateFile`, because that's the one that was imported in the java file where that constructor is defined.
- You're actually passing `dto.m.CreateFile` to the constructor, because that's the one that was imported in the java file where you're calling the constructor.

Because these two classes are different, an object of the second class can't be passed to the constructor with a parameter whose type is the first class.

Comment: I 'm Updating my post , I need to match a CreateFileAction on argument of contructor.  I modify the getConstructor() and he don't know the contructor

Comment: But in your class, the constructor takes a `CreateFile`, not a `CreateFileAction`.

Comment: I updating my post , If i make CreateFile , I have an error NoSuchMethodException

Comment: So, is the `CreateFile` imported by the `CreateFileAction` class the same as the `CreateFile` imported by the class where the exception is thrown from?

Comment: the exception is thrown from with that : actionClass.getConstructor(CreateFile.class); //  with that CreateFile.class.   

I test with other parameter in my CreateFileAction Class with a String parameter ( String.class) and it's work , but not with  CreateFile.class

Comment: But do the `import` statements match up?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why if I put this parameter it's not working.   because dto is an instance of CreateFile for example and it's not working with CreateFile.class parameter in the GetConstructor()

Comment: OK, show us the two `import` statements where `CreateFile` is imported.  Both the one in `CreateFileAction.java` and also the one in whatever file the code in that first grey block comes from.

Comment: OK, and what about the import on CreateFileAction.java?

Comment: it's in the Class<?> actionClass

Comment: No, I want the `import` statement that imports the `CreateFile` class, at the top of `CreateFileAction.java`.  I thought I made this clear.

Comment: ah yes sorry ,  
in my CreateFileAction :  import dto.mToInte.CreateFile;

Comment: You told me an hour ago that the imports matched.  They don't.  I have edited my answer to include what your current problem is.

Comment: I modify my code with the dto.mToInte.CreateFile ,  I have the same problem. ----  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: inteToM.CreateFileAction.<init>(dto.mToInte.CreateFile)  in the getContructor(dto.mToInte.CreateFile.class); -----   I modify my post.

Comment: Well, you've made so many modifications to the question, it's hard to tell what code you have any more.  Your latest change to the `CreateFileAction` class isn't even in the right place.  Please post both the classes again, exactly as they are now, as an edit at the end of the question, and I'll copy them into my IDE and get them working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an instance of `CreateFile` as the argument.

Comment: If i make CreateFile as the argument it's not working too. same error